# C poll() returns ECHILD

Tags: c, errno

Just encountered an undocumented error. The call to `poll()` returned `ECHILD`.

I have a very simple code, almost directly from the man:

```
struct pollfd fds[] = { fd, POLLIN, 0 };
while(should_continue) {
  int rc=poll(fds, 1, 1000);
  if(rc==0) {
     // exit by timeout, repeat waiting
     continue;
  } else if(rc<0) {
     printf("poll error %d\n", errno);
     exit(1);
  }
  // read from fd
}
```

This code suddenly exited with "poll error 10". But `man 2 poll` does not even mention ECHILD as possible error. What could be the cause?

Comment: You're better off using `perror()` to print errno codes.

Comment: The variable `fds` should be an array of structure, I recommend you be more explicit about it with e.g. `struct pollfd fds[] = { { fd, POLLIN, 0 } };`

Comment: I suspect you have a signal handler that clobbers `errno`. Specifically, one that handles `SIGCHLD` and calls `wait` until it returns `-1`.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you have a signal handler that clobbers `errno`. Specifically, a `SIGCHLD` handler that calls `wait` until it returns `-1`.

What happens is this:

1. You call `poll` and it blocks.
2. A child exits.
3. `poll` returns error `EINTR` to allow your signal handler a chance to run.
4. Your `SIGCHLD` handler is called.
5. It calls `wait` repeatedly to reap every child waiting to be reaped.
6. The last call to `wait`, having nothing left to reap, returns error `ECHILD`.
7. Your `SIGCHLD` handler returns *without restoring `errno`*.
8. `poll` appears to have returned error `ECHILD` when it really returned error `EINTR`.

Fix:

- Save `errno` when your signal handler is called, and restore it before exiting.
- Restart `poll` when it returns error `EINTR`, or make it so it's automatically restarted after signal processing by setting up your signal handler using `sigaction` and passing the appropriate flags.

Very few things return error `ECHILD`, so the possible explanations are very limited. As such, I'm pretty confident in my guess.

---

Notes:

- "Returns error `EXXX`" is used as shorthand for "returns `-1` after setting `errno` to `EXXX`".

Comment: I would have thought that `errno` would be set for an interrupted system call *after* the signal handler has returned.

Comment: What model crystal-ball are you using? I want one.